# Get metadata from multiple files in multiple locations

Tags: vb.net, metadata

I'm trying to access metadata from multiple files.  I already have code that I found to grab the metadata, but I need to be able to grab from multiple files in different folders.  The file types are all the same. Is this possible?  If so, can it be added to the current code?

Eventaully, I'd like to grab all the metadata and send it to a database for doing comparisons.

This is the code I found that I used to get it from 1 file in one location:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.IO
Imports Shell32


Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call Main()
End Sub

Sub Main()
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = "D:\Folder\Folder1\filename.pst"
    Dim Properties As Dictionary(Of Integer, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) = GetFileProperties(FileName)
    For Each FileProperty As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) In Properties
        ListBox1.Items.Add(FileProperty.Value.Key & ": " & FileProperty.Value.Value)
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetFileProperties(ByVal FileName As String) As Dictionary(Of Integer, KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
    Dim Shell As New Shell
    Dim Folder As Folder = Shell.[NameSpace](Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName))
    Dim File As FolderItem = Folder.ParseName(Path.GetFileName(FileName))
    Dim Properties As New Dictionary(Of Integer, KeyValuePair(Of String, String))()
    Dim Index As Integer
    Dim Keys As Integer = Folder.GetDetailsOf(File, 0).Count
    For Index = 0 To Keys - 1
        Dim CurrentKey As String = Folder.GetDetailsOf(Nothing, Index)
        Dim CurrentValue As String = Folder.GetDetailsOf(File, Index)
        If CurrentValue <> "" Then
            Properties.Add(Index, New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(CurrentKey, CurrentValue))
        End If
    Next
    Return Properties
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: In your example file path is hard-coded. You need to get files in List or string array and iterate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if below code helps -

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.IO
Imports Shell32


Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call Main()
End Sub

Sub Main()

    Dim dir As New IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\")
    Dim files As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.pst")
    Dim file As IO.FileInfo
    Dim FileName As String

    For Each file In files

        FileName = file.FullName

        Dim Properties As Dictionary(Of Integer, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) = GetFileProperties(FileName)
        For Each FileProperty As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) In Properties
            ListBox1.Items.Add(FileProperty.Value.Key & ": " & FileProperty.Value.Value)
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetFileProperties(ByVal FileName As String) As Dictionary(Of Integer, KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
    Dim Shell As New Shell
    Dim Folder As Folder = Shell.[NameSpace](Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName))
    Dim File As FolderItem = Folder.ParseName(Path.GetFileName(FileName))
    Dim Properties As New Dictionary(Of Integer, KeyValuePair(Of String, String))()
    Dim Index As Integer
    Dim Keys As Integer = Folder.GetDetailsOf(File, 0).Count
    For Index = 0 To Keys - 1
        Dim CurrentKey As String = Folder.GetDetailsOf(Nothing, Index)
        Dim CurrentValue As String = Folder.GetDetailsOf(File, Index)
        If CurrentValue <> "" Then
            Properties.Add(Index, New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(CurrentKey, CurrentValue))
        End If
    Next
    Return Properties
End Function

End Class
```

Above code will search for all .pst files in C:\ and read the properties.
To allow different folders you need to create array of directories and read them from configuration file or any other location as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you - that does seem to help!  I was able to get the data I needed from the files I had in 1 folder.  Now on to accessing multiple folders!